# Recent movie/TV series with black alien goop that takes over people

Tags: story-identification, movie, aliens

I saw a trailer a few years ago (post 2000) of this movie.

There were these people in some sort of space station, I think.  They looked at this door that had a window on it, and then this blob of black alien goop splattered itself against the window.

Best way I can describe it is it looked like the Venom symbiote from Marvel. It would go and take over the people one by one and the people had to try to get out of the space station. I can't remember anything else, but it has been bugging me so badly.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  How did it take people over if they were on the other side of a window?  What did they do once they were taken over?  How were they shown to be taken over?

Answer (score 4):

Might this be the 2017 film *[Life](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Life_(2017_film))*?

> In the film, a six-member crew of the International Space Station uncovers the first evidence of extraterrestrial life on Mars. When members of the crew conduct their research, the rapidly evolving life-form proves to be far more intelligent than expected and terrifying.

### Trailer

Comment: Hmm... less gooey than I remembered: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xscuyjf08_Q